# String array elements OrderBy itself

Tags: c#, arrays, linq

If I have a string array like this:

```
string[] str = new string[]{"abc", "bacd", "pacds"};
```

Then I need output like below using LINQ:

> output: abc, abcd, acdps

Comment: Can you please show some code showing what you've tried so far? And where exactly are you stuck?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be what you want:

```
string[] str = new string[] { "abc", "bacd", "pacds" };
var result = str.Select(c => String.Concat(c.OrderBy(d => d)));
```

The `result` is `IEnumerable<string>` but if you want the result in an string array add `.ToArray()`:

```
var result = str.Select(c => String.Concat(c.OrderBy(d => d))).ToArray();
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: Since 2022, instead of `c.OrderBy(d => d)` one can do `c.Order()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `String.Concat(st.OrderBy(c => c))` to order string by its characters.

```
str.ToList().ForEach((val) => {
    val = String.Concat(val.OrderBy(c => c));
});
```

Comment: Since 2022, instead of `val.OrderBy(c => c)` one can do `val.Order()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
str.Select(x => x.ToCharArray().OrderBy(c => c).Aggregate("", (s,c)=>s+c))
```

Answer (score 0):

this just to change the array strings into chars-ordered ones

```
    static void orderChars(string[] str)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
            str[i] = new string(str[i].OrderBy(c => c).ToArray());
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

As bassfader commented , show your code and say where u stuck , then we can guide you, anyway ..

You can write it like this ,

> string[] a = new string[]
>   {"Indonesian","Korean","Japanese","English","German"};
>
> var sort = from s in a   orderby s select s;